# Android Compound View Usage

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 buttons for Terms and Conditions in my project, that I need to implement in multiple activities. I created the following class:

```
public class TermsAndConditionsView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context context;

    public TermsAndConditionsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TermsAndConditionsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        setUpLayout();
    }

    private void setUpLayout() {
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) this.getChildAt(1);
        Button terms1 = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.terms1);
        Button terms2 = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.terms2);
        terms1.setOnClickListener(this);
        terms2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.terms1) {
            String url = "myUrl1";
            ActivityUtil.openBrowser((Activity) context, url);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.terms2) {
            String url = "myUrl2";
            ActivityUtil.openBrowser((Activity) context, url);
        }
    }
}
```

And the **terms.xml** file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.TermsAndConditionsView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hosted_by_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/title_grey"
    style="@style/text1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/terms1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Terms 1"
        style="@style/Link2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/terms2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Terms 2"
        style="@style/Link2"/>
</LinearLayout>
</com.example.TermsAndConditionsView>
```

Is this a good way of reusing a group of views?

My colleagues say that it's not ok to use an XML which can be modified easily because I should modify in the code also (for example changing the order of the views) and if I am not careful the app might crash and it might take some time to figure out from where the problem comes from.

So, what's the best way of reusing this group of Terms and Conditions buttons?

Answer (score 3):

Usually I use this approach when I want to create custom views but I don't implement actions inside the view, instead I am using a callback like the click listener :).

Also another minor thing is that there is no need to do `getChildAt()` so you can find a specific view from a child view if you don't happen to have id's with the same names. Instead you can call `findViewById` directly on **this**(the root view).